# Are there plans to place the logo on the PDF at the same location as on the form?

Tags: cognito-forms

The ability to add and center logos on the form was a great addition to the tool.
However when I create the PDF or the email notification the logo is left justified.

Answer (score 1):

I work for Cognito Forms.  There is no plan for that functionality currently.  However, I have added it as an enhancement request.  Please do note that you can center your logo and customize the PDF however you like using the Manage Template feature on paid plans.